# Is there a common framework for Tannaka and Gabriel-Ulmer reconstruction theorems?

Tags: ct.category-theory, rt.representation-theory, big-picture

[Gabriel-Ulmer duality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gabriel-Ulmer+duality) is a biequivalence between the 2-category of finite limit categories and the 2-category of locally finitely presentable categories. It allows for the reconstruction of a theory from the category of models of that theory, for example, the theory of groups from its category of models. There are other related dualities corresponding to other 'doctrines', see [A Duality Relative to a Limit Doctrine](http://perso.uclouvain.be/enrico.vitale/DLP6.pdf).

This idea of recovering something from its category of models seems to resemble closely the [Tannakian reconstruction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tannaka+duality) of an algebraic entity from its category of modules or comodules or whatever.

So I was wondering whether there is a way to see doctrinal, Gabriel-Ulmer style reconstruction and Tannaka style reconstruction as instances of something more general.

The only explicit reference I have found is Brian Day in [Enriched Tannaka reconstruction](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404995000399) writing "Our approach provides a synthesis of Tannaka reconstruction and Gabriel-Ulmer duality," but I haven't found the paper very helpful.

I've posed this question at greater length [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/07/doctrinal_and_tannakian_recons.html).

Comment: Why the vote to close??? 

Comment: Someone thought I was asking about Gabriel-Rosenberg, the connection of which with Tannaka reconstruction has already been asked about.
They withdrew the comment, but can't withdraw the vote.

Comment: Todd provided an answer here http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/07/doctrinal_and_tannakian_recons.html#c038868.